# How can users use Web Bluetooth apps on iOS?

Tags: web-bluetooth

Is Web Bluetooth implemented in Safari? How can web apps that use Web Bluetooth on their pages work on Apple iphones and ipads?

Answer (score 3):

[Safari has not implemented](https://github.com/WebBluetoothCG/web-bluetooth/blob/master/implementation-status.md#safari) the [Web Bluetooth](https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/web-bluetooth/) specification, however [WebBLE](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/webble/id1193531073&sa=D&ust=1503012579131000&usg=AFQjCNEgfDONFvoh6zxVlEdZdvFbTUTlAA) is an [open source](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://github.com/daphtdazz/BleBrowser&sa=D&ust=1503012579131000&usg=AFQjCNF0vdfvejiGTkpXzPPp0dl636Nt0A) browser implementation that supports Web Bluetooth.

You can have users use [WebBLE](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/webble/id1193531073&sa=D&ust=1503012579131000&usg=AFQjCNEgfDONFvoh6zxVlEdZdvFbTUTlAA) directly, or use the code to build your own hybrid app that wraps your web app.